Error Running TypeScript File with esrun: Module Not Found
I am trying to execute a TypeScript file with esrun, but I encounter the following error:
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Diogo Barros\Documents\projects\spl-token\node_modules\.bin\node_modules\@solana-developers\helpers\dist\index.js' imported from 'C:\Users\Diogo Barros\Documents\projects\spl-token\node_modules\.bin\esrun-1717410142669.tmp.mjs'

It should be importing from:
'C:\Users\Diogo Barros\Documents\projects\spl-token\node_modules\@solana-developers\helpers\dist\index.js'

Here is the code where I am trying to import:
import { createMint, getAssociatedTokenAddress, getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount } from "@solana/spl-token";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config()
import {
  getKeypairFromEnvironment,
  getExplorerLink,
} from "@solana-developers/helpers";
import { Connection,PublicKey, clusterApiUrl } from "@solana/web3.js";

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));

const user = getKeypairFromEnvironment("SECRET_KEY");

console.log(
  ` Loaded our keypair securely, using an env file! Our public key is: ${user.publicKey.toBase58()}`
);

const tokenMintAccount = new PublicKey(
    "XyCbpUa4uzmVD5KLAHUujV73X81ErvfhdWFCLWa5v7N"
);
// Here we are making an associated token account for our own address, but we can 
// make an ATA on any other wallet in devnet!
// const recipient = new PublicKey("SOMEONE_ELSES_DEVNET_ADDRESS");
const recipient = user.publicKey;

const tokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
    connection,
    user,
    tokenMintAccount,
    recipient
);

console.log(`Token Account: ${tokenAccount.address.toBase58()}`);

const link = getExplorerLink(
  "address",
  tokenAccount.address.toBase58(),
  "devnet"
);

console.log(`✅ Created token Account: ${link}`);


I have already tried removing node_modules and package-lock.json, but nothing has worked. Can anyone help?
Thank you in advance!

Try

delete node modules folder (rm -rf ./node_modules)
npm i -g esrun
try again


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
